# Is there way to change to instance type in Azure Cloud Services

Tags: azure, cloud

Is there any way to change the **VM Size** of an Azure Cloud Service without having to rebuild the package?

The `vmsize` parameter is defined in the `.csdef` file rather than the `.cscfg` file that is uploaded into Azure and doesn't appear in the other included XML files of the package.

Please note that we're not looking to change the **instance count** (scale out) but the size type (i.e. from Extra Small (A0) to Medium (A2)).

Comment: Would you be so kind to edit your question and express yourself more clearly. I am having hard time to understand what exactly are you asking! And what do you mean by "Instance Type" ?

Comment: @user145610: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 10):

The vmsize is attribute of csdef file and not of ServiceConfiguration.cscfg

You can see on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj156212.aspx

Answer (score 9):

Yes, when you create your service model, you can specify the size to which to deploy an instance of your role, depending on its resource requirements. The size of the role determines the number of CPU cores, the memory capacity, and the local file system size that is allocated to a running instance.

Basically, you need to change the “vmsize” parameter in the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file to the required value (vmsize="[ExtraSmall|Small|Medium|Large|ExtraLarge]") and re-deploy the package back to Azure.

http://www.nimbo.com/blog/changing-the-instance-size-from-the-windows-azure-management-portal/

Comment: Our cspkg file is already in production,now we can't generate package again and redeploy back

Comment: you need to change through the Windows Azure management portal. Just select your cloud services -> scale then change the size / number of instances

Comment: we have provision of changing Azure VM Size Type in Azure Management portal. we need to generate package one more package

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand. You need another package but you can't generate through VS, am I correct?

Comment: Yeah there was spelling mistake in the above comment. We want make change of VM Size withoout recompiling and generate new package

Comment: as I said, you can change it through windows azure management portal or through REST API http://www.jstawski.com/archive/2012/08/10/Scaling-OutIn-with-the-Azure-Management-API.aspx

Comment: Scaling Up/Down (VM Size) only seems to happen at build time, while scaling in/out (instance count) is available through the portal for cloud services. Actual VMs can indeed be scaled up and down.

Comment: You can scale the VM up and down using Azure Resource Manager REST API

Comment: @SteveFord do you have an example/link for that?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio: You cannot add `vmsize="ExtraSmall"` to the `Role` tag in the `.cscfg` file(s) - just the `.csdef` files. Which is exact problem asked by the OP. If you add to the `.cscfg` files, VS2015 (Azure tool 2.7) throws an error.

Comment: this answer is just for the type of the VMSize, but you have to increase the scale by login to the portal

Answer (score 2):

You can use Azure Powershell:

```
C:\PS>Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "MySvc1" -Name "MyVM3" | Set-AzureVMSize "Basic_A2" | Update-AzureVM
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like that should work, however just trying `Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "MySvc1" | Format-Table "Name","InstanceStatus"` results in the simple response "Completed Operation: Get Deployment" but no output or details of the VMs. Supplying a specific VM name results in the same thing.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid can you log in to https://portal.azure.com and check that you have a virtual machine deployed, you also might want to check whether you have more than one subscription. I've just tried my command and it works fine.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid you can slo change it directky in the portal https://portal.azure.com

Comment: Sadly, this is a full cloud service with web and worker roles, not a cloud service fronting a single VM, so the portal doesn't let me resize the VM on the fly. If I call this on a cloud service with no instances running I get the message saying there are no deployments.