# Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Since a few months i'm using Azure services. Yesterday I created an Azure Cloud Service that is running fine. What I don't understand is how to scale it up or down. The default value is "A1 (1 core, 1.75 GB memory)", but when I look at the pricing page, I see different options, for example A0, A1, A2, A3 etc.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cloud-services/

Can anyone tell me how to scale for more or less memory. I like to start with the A0 instance, but I can't find the option.

Thanks!

Comment: Answer already found:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082793/is-there-way-to-change-to-instance-type-in-azure-cloud-services][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082793/is-there-way-to-change-to-instance-type-in-azure-cloud-services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this in two ways:

1. You can edit the ServiceDefinition.csdef configuration file in your cloud project and set the `vmsize` attribute to `ExtraSmall` (or the size you wish to use for your service).
2. By using the graphic interface: double click on the role you want to modify (or right click, then select Preferences) and select the `VM size` you wish from the list.

Remember that to change the VM size for your deployed roles you will need to do a new deployment. But, if you want to change the instance count, you can scale your role while it's running.