# Why does manually modifying azure cloud package and deploying it for changing instance size fail?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-deployment

Now [I got to know](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0652d2e7-4469-4b30-b100-dd82485ceffd/azure-resize-instance-from-small-to-medium-in-cloud-service?forum=windowsazuremanagement) we can't change the cloud service instance size without having to redeploy the package. But consider a scenario where we only have the package directly and don't have access to the code. And this package has a wrong instance size mentioned in the `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file. What to do if we want to manually modify the instance size?

So I tried to modify the `.cspkg` file manually by first changing the extension as `.zip`. Then inside that there was a `.csdx` file; which I again changed to zip and inside that there was the `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file.

I changed the VM instance size to the required size and basically did a reverse operation to the above steps and created the `.cspkg` again. **Note that I took enough care to maintain the levels of each files within the package**.

But when I tried to deploy this modified package, I got an exception in the portal that it was not a valid service package.

Any idea why that would fail? I mean, are there other things also on which the instance size is dependent on? And what all are they in the `.cspkg` package?

I also referred to the below links for reference.

[Is there way to change to instance type in Azure Cloud Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082793/is-there-way-to-change-to-instance-type-in-azure-cloud-services)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/0652d2e7-4469-4b30-b100-dd82485ceffd/azure-resize-instance-from-small-to-medium-in-cloud-service?forum=windowsazuremanagement

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the cloud service packages are signed, requiring construction from the Visual Studio tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cspack tool to repackage with binaries with new csdef file. Refer: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-model-and-package/

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I unzipped the cspkg and got the csdef and the actual package binaries. Then executed the below command for generating another package.
cspack.exe "path_to_csdef_File\ServiceDefinition.csdef" /role:<RoleName>;<path_to_Binaries\approot> /out:D:\NewPackage.cspkg /rolePropertiesFile:<rolename>;<path_to_entry_point_file\entrypoint.txt>